# iPhone 5s Keeps Crashing to Safe Mode

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, crash

My iPhone is jailbroken and it keeps crashing to safe mode randomly.

I have two pastebins of crashlogs. [Here's crash 1](http://pastebin.com/v8XEc0CU) and [here's crash 2.](http://pastebin.com/D0kuqtsj)

And here is a list of my jailbreak tweaks.

Packages

```
3x4 Centered (No Icon Labels) Iconoclasm Layout - 1.0

4x3 (iPhone 5) Iconoclasm Layouts - 1.0

4x5 Dense Layout for Iconoclasm - 1.0

7-zip (POSIX) - 4.57-3p

Activator - 1.8.4~beta6

adv-cmds - 119-5

animate - 1.0.1-1

Animate fix for iOS 7.x.x - 1.0

Animer7 - 1.0

AppInfo - 1.6

AppList - 1.5.7

Applocker - 2.2.5

APR (/usr/lib) - 1.3.3-2

APT 0.6 Transitional - 1:0-23

APT 0.7 (apt-key) - 0.7.25.3-3

APT 0.7 HTTPS Method - 0.7.25.3-3

APT 0.7 Strict - 0.7.25.3-6

APT 0.7 Strict (lib) - 0.7.25.3-11

AutoPause - 1.0

Base Structure - 1-4

BaSic-AdBlocker7 - 1.0.2

BatteryLife - 1.3.1

Berkeley DB - 4.6.21-4p

BigBoss Icon Set - 1.0

BioCentered HD - 1

biteSMS - 8.1.3

Bolt - 0.7.0

Bourne-Again SHell - 4.0.17-13

BytaFont 2 - 2.1.3

bzip2 - 1.0.5-7

CameraTweak 2 (iOS 7) - 1.0.1

CleverPin - 1.8-3

ColorBadges - 1.0.3-2

ColorFlow - 1.0.5-1

Coono - 1.1-4P

Core Utilities - 8.12-12p

Core Utilities (/bin) - 8.12-7p

Crash Reporter - 0.2g-1

cURL - 7.33.0-8

customLS - 1.2-1

Cycript - 0.9.501

Cydget - 0.9.4011

Cydia Installer - 1.1.9

Cydia Substrate - 0.9.5001

Cydia Translations - 1.1.8.1

Cylinder - 0.13.2.15

Darwin Tools - 1-4

Debian Packager - 1.14.25-9

Debian Utilities - 3.3.3ubuntu1-1p

Diff Utilities - 2.8.1-6

Disable Parallax Effect - 1.3-1

diskdev-cmds - 421.7-4

DockShift - 1.4-2

Eclipse - 1.1.3-3

evasi0n 7.x Untether - 0.3

Exigency - 1.1.1

f.lux - 0.986

f.lux Flipswitch - 0.2-1

file-cmds - 220.7-3

Find Utilities - 4.2.33-6

FlagPaint7 - 1.0

Flex 2 - 1.928

FlipControlCenter - 1.0

Flipswitch - 1.0.3

GIFViewer - 1.0-1

GNU Privacy Guard - 1.4.16-1

grep - 2.5.4-3

GridSwitcher - 1.0-2

gzip - 1.6-7

HASHBANG Productions Common - 1.0

Hattori Hanzo Font - 1.0

HomeLock - 1.2

iCleaner Pro - 7.1.3-1

IconBundles - 0.1-3

Iconoclasm - 1.9.1

IconSupport - 1.9.2-1

iFile - 2.0.1-1

iOS 7 Blank Keypad - 0.0.2

iOS Firmware - 7.0.6

iPhone Firmware (/sbin) - 0-1

iTunes Radio Unlimited - 1.1.0

Lato Light Font - 1.2

libhide - 2.4.1-1

libstatusbar - 0.9.7.0

LockSafety - 1.0-1

lscameragrabber - 1.1

LZMA Utils - 4.32.7-4

MessagesCustomiser - 2.3.4-2

NCAllOnly - 2.2-1

NCSingleTapClear - 1.0-2

New Curses - 5.7-13

Nitrous - 2.4-5

No Yahoo! - 1.0-1

NoAnnoyance - 0.2.0~beta4-1

NoDelay64 - 1.1-2

NoSlowAnimations - 3.0.1-3

NoStoreButton7 - 1.0-2

OpenSSH - 6.5p1-2

OpenSSL - 0.9.8y-10

PAM (Apple) - 32.1-3

PAM Modules - 36.1-4

pcre - 8.30-5p

Phantom - 2.6.3-1

Photo Blackground - 1.0-8

PhotoTorch - 1.3-7

pincrush - 0.9.2-1

PowerSoundDisabler - 1.1.1-6

PreferenceLoader - 2.2.2

PreferenceOrganizer 2 - 1.0-2

Profile Directory - 0-2

Pulse - 1.0-1

readline - 6.0-7

RocketBootstrap - 1.0.1

SameStatus - 1.0-1

SandCastle 2 - 2.2-1

sed - 4.1.5-7

shell-cmds - 118-6

Show Notification Dates - 1.0-2

ShowCase - 1.3.4.1-1

Shrink - 1.0.7.0

SlideForUsage - 0.0.4

Springtomize 3 - iOS 7 - 1.1.0-2

SSH Switch - 1.2

StatusBarFix2 - 0.1.2-1

StatusHUD 2 - 2.0.0

StatusModifier - 2.0.1

StoreAlert - 1.0-2

Substrate Safe Mode - 0.9.4000

Subtle7 - 0.1

SwipeSelection - 1.4.1-1

SwitchSpring - 1.0.1

syslogd to /var/log/syslog - 1.0.2586-2

system-cmds - 433.4-12

Tape Archive - 1.19-8

TinyBar - 0.0.4-1

UIKit Tools - 1.1.8

Ultimate M'Flat Icon Collection - 1.7

Uniformity - 0.0.1~beta4-1

unrar - 3.6.8-2p

unzip - 5.52-5p

WiFi Booster - 2.0

WinterBoard - 0.9.3915

YouTubed - 1.2-2

Zanilla - 2.1.1

zip - 2.32-5p
```

Sorry I can only post 2 links since I'm a new member. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much for looking!

Comment: Remove the tweaks one by one, starting with the tweak you've installed last. One of the tweaks is messing up.

Comment: Only problem is, I just got the phone Monday and installed all my tweaks at the same time that I had on my 4S. But alright, I'll try when I have free time. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your comment Iounno, the fact that you had the same tweaks on a 4S is irrelevant.

Comment: Because they were stable on my 4S, they should be stable on my 5s unless the tweak is unsupported (all are). So I'd assume it should work fine on my 5s, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Crash Reporter**](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/crash-reporter).

Crash Reporter will attempt to guess the cause of a crash. After installing, next time your iPhone crashes, you can check the 'Possible Causes' list in Crash Reporter for its guess on the cause. You can then try to delete the package in Cydia and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: It doesn't for me for some reason. Just shows nothing. Though I remembered there was an issue with libhide on my 4S so I disabled it through iCleaner and my phone hasn't crashed yet, so that was probably it.

Edit: and now it did. Awesome.

Answer (score -1):

I had a crash if I used the flipcontrolcenter. I removed nitrous and all is fine again.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove this tweak (StatusHUD 2 - 2.0.0)